# Prove $\ell_1$ is complete

Tags: analysis

I try to prove that $\ell_1$, the space of absolutely convergent sequences in $\mathbb{C}$ with norm $\| x \| = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_k|$, is complete.
I already proved that, if $\{ x_n \}$ is a Cauchy sequence (with elements in $\ell_1$), then, for a fixed $k \in \mathbb{N}$, the sequence $\{ x_{n,k} \}$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{C}$.

The obvious way to define a limit of a Cauchy sequence $\{ x_n \}$ is to take the limits of $\{ x_{n,k}\}$, which exist since $\mathbb{C}$ is complete. Let's call this sequence $x$.
But now we only know $x_n \to x$ pointwise.

**Problem:** how do I prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} \| x_n - x \| = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_{n,k} - x_k| = 0$?

I suppose I need to use the absolute convergence of $x_n$, but I do not see how. If I can prove the above, it follows that $x \in \ell_1$ therefore $\ell_1$ is complete.

**Edit:** Knowing $x \in \ell_1$, to establish convergence, I know (for $n,m>N$) $\sum_{k=1}^K |x_{m,k} − x_{n,k} | \leq \|x_m−x_n\| < \epsilon$. I let $m \to \infty$, can I conclude $\sum_{k=1}^K |x_k − x_{n,k}| \leq \| x−x_n \| < \epsilon$? That seems odd. But so does $\sum^K_{k=1} | x_k − x_{n,k} | \leq \| x_m − x_n \|$. What can I say when $m \to \infty$?

Comment: This is a special case of the Fischer-Riesz theorem. The trick is to pick a subsequence $(n_k)$ such that $\|x_{n_{k-1}}-x_{n_k}\|\le 1/2^k$. Then the crucial estimate comes down to a geometric series.

Comment: You can use the fact that the norm is a continuous function to introduce the limit into the norm.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328479/completeness-proof-of-ellp).

Comment: Knowing $x \in \ell_1$, to establish convergence, I know (for $n, m > N$) $\sum_{k=1}^K |x_{m,k} - x_{n,k}| \leq \| x_m - x_n \| < \epsilon$. I let $m \to \infty$, can I conclude $\sum_{k=1}^K |x_k - x_{n,k}| \leq \| x - x_n \| < \epsilon$? That seems odd. But so does $\sum_{k=1}^K | x_k - x_{n,k} | \leq \| x_m - x_n \|$. What can I say when $m \to \infty$?