# Prove that $\ell ^1(\mathbb{N})$ is a Banach space.

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I'm trying to prove that $\ell^1(\mathbb{N}) := \left\{ (x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} : \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_n\right| < \infty \right\} $, the space of all sequences over the field $\mathbb{C}$ that converge absolutely, is a Banach space with respect to the norm $\left|\left|(x_n)\right|\right|_{1} :=  \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_n\right|$.

Proof thus far:

Suppose $(x_n)\in L^1(\mathbb{N})$  and let $X^{(l)} := \left\{(x_{n})_{l}\right\}^{\infty}_{l=1} \subset \ell^1(\mathbb{N}) $ denote a Cauchy sequence.

Therefore, $\forall ~ \epsilon > 0, \exists ~ N \in \mathbb{N} : \left|\left| X^{(l)} - X^{(m)}\right|\right|_{1} < \epsilon   \space\space \forall ~ l,m \ge N $.

By definition, $\left|\left| X^{(l)} - X^{(m)}\right|\right|_{1} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \left|x^{(l)}_k - x^{(m)}_k\right| \le \epsilon$

So, $\left| \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(x^{(l)}_k - x^{(m)}_k\right) \right| \leq  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \left|x^{(l)}_k - x^{(m)}_k\right| \le \epsilon$

We then have,  $\forall ~ \epsilon > 0, \exists ~ N \in \mathbb{N} : \left| \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} x^{(l)}_k - x^{(m)}_k\right| < \epsilon \space\space  \forall ~ l,m \ge N $

The summation is over each element of the Cauchy sequence $X^{(l)}$, which are themselves Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{C}$ and so therefore must converge (since $\mathbb{C}$ is a Banach space).

I'm not sure where to go from here though, how to relate that back to the original Cauchy sequence in $L^1(\mathbb{N})$ to show that it converges. Or even what I've done already is even correct.

Comment: I'm a little confused at your notation.  Since $L^1(\mathbb{N})$ is a space of sequences, shouldn't the Cauchy sequence be a "sequence of sequences," i.e., $\left\lbrace (x_n^{(j)})\right\rbrace_{j = 1}^{\infty}$ so that, say, $\displaystyle \Vert (x^{(j)}) - (x^{(k)}) \Vert = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \vert x_n^{(j)} - x_n^{(k)} \vert$?

Comment: Yes I think you're right, i hadn't thought of that

Answer (score 5):

Here's the start of the answer.  Let $\displaystyle \left\lbrace ( x^{(j)}_n )_{n = 1}^{\infty} \right\rbrace_{j = 1}^{\infty}$ be the Cauchy sequence of $L^1 (\mathbb{N})$ (usually called $\ell^1$) sequences, so that

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \, J :\,  j, k \geq J \text{ implies } \Vert(x^{(j)}_n) - (x^{(k)}_n)\Vert_1 = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(j)}_n - x^{(k)}_n \vert  < \epsilon.$$

**Claim:** We know what the limit sequence must be, termwise.

*Proof:*  Fixing a specific index $m$, we clearly have that $\vert x^{(j)}_m - x^{(k)}_m \vert \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(j)}_n - x^{(k)}_n \vert$, so that we conclude:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \, J :\,  j, k \geq J \text{ implies } \vert x^{(j)}_m - x^{(k)}_m \vert \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(j)}_n - x^{(k)}_n \vert  < \epsilon.$$

Hence, $(x_m^{(j)})_{j = 1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence of complex numbers, hence converges.  We define the limiting value as
$$x^{(\infty)}_m : = \lim_{j \to \infty} x_m^{(j)}.$$

Of course, we can repeat for each $m \in \mathbb{N}$.  Therefore, our goal is to show that the termwise/"pointwise"  limit $(x_n^{(\infty)})_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is an $L^1(\mathbb{N})$ sequence. **EDIT** Also, we need to show that  that $\lbrace (x^{(j)}) \rbrace_{j = 1}^{\infty}$ converges to it. **TIDE**  $\square$

The remainder is a fairly standard "split the error into digestible pieces each less than $\displaystyle \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ or $\displaystyle \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ or whatever the fraction is," similar to the proof that the uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous.  **EDIT** This paragraph is too simplistic.  See below. **TIDE**  Do you require further assistance, or can you take it from here?

**P.S.:** This method does not really generalize that well outside sequence spaces.  The general proof of completeness of $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ requires some use of the Dominated Convergence Theorem, and the fact that completeness is equivalent to "absolute convergence of series implies convergence of series."

---

**EDIT:** The middle of the proof.  Our goal here is to show that the "limit object" is in the space of $\ell^1$ sequences.

**Lemma 1:** $M: = \sup_j \Vert (x_n^{(j)}) \Vert_1 < \infty$.  (i.e., "Cauchy sequences are bounded").

*Proof:*  Fix $\epsilon = 1$.  Then by Cauchy-ness, $$\exists J: j, k \geq J \, \text{ implies } \, \Vert (x_n^{(j)}) - (x_n^{(k)}) \Vert_1 < 1.$$
Fixing $j = J$, then we have that for all $k \geq J$, 
$$ \begin{align} \Vert (x^{(k)}_n) \Vert_1 & \leq \Vert (x_n^{(k)}) - (x_n^{(J)}) \Vert_1 + \Vert (x_n^{(J)}) \Vert_1 \\
& \leq 1 + \Vert (x_n^{(J)}) \Vert_1 \end{align}$$
Thus, it is clear that the larger of $\displaystyle \max_{1 \leq k < J} \Vert (x_n^{(k)}) \Vert_1$ and $1 + \Vert (x_n^{(J)}) \Vert_1 $  is an upper bound on all $ \Vert (x_n^{(k)}) \Vert_1.$  Hence, the supremum is finite. $\square$

Our next trick is to show that all the partial sums are uniformly bounded.

**Claim:** For all $N \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$S_N := \sum_{n = 1}^N \vert x_n^{(\infty)} \vert \leq M + 1.$$

*Proof:* Fix $N \in \mathbb{N}$.  By the Triangle Inequality, for any choice of $j$,
$$  \sum_{n = 1}^N \vert x_n^{(\infty)}\vert \leq \sum_{n = 1}^N \vert x_n^{(\infty)} - x_n^{(j)} \vert + \sum_{n = 1}^N \vert x_n^{(j)}\vert.$$

We need to choose $j$ so that both sums are bounded.

*The first sum:* Note that for all $n \in \lbrace 1, 2, 3, \dotsc, N \rbrace$, we know that $\displaystyle x^{(\infty)}_n  = \lim_{j \to \infty} x_n^{(j)}$.  Hence, fixing $\displaystyle \epsilon = \frac{1}{N}$,

$$ \exists J_n : j \geq J_n \text{ implies that } \vert x_n^{(\infty)} - x_n^{(j)} \vert < \frac{1}{N}.$$
  Taking $\displaystyle J^* := \max_{1 \leq n \leq N}  J_n$, we have that
$$
j \geq J^* \text{ implies } \sum_{n = 1}^N \vert x_n^{(\infty)} - x_n^{(j)} \vert  < \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{1}{N} = 1.
 $$
We will, in fact, for convenience take $j = J^*$, and the first sum is bounded by $1$.

*The second sum:*  Clearly 
$$\sum_{n = 1}^N \vert x_n^{(J^*)} \vert \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \vert x_n^{(J^*)} \vert = \Vert (x_n^{(J^*)}) \Vert_1.$$  Yet this sum, by Lemma 1 is bounded by $M$.

Combining the above results, we get that $S_N \leq 1 + M$, as required.  $\square$

**Claim:** $(x_n^{(\infty)})$ is in $L^1(\mathbb{N})$.

*Proof Sketch:* Clearly $S_N$ is increasing in $N$, yet bounded above independently of $N$.  As soon as you see that $S_N$ converges, then by definition of infinite sums of real numbers, $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \vert x_n^{(\infty)} \vert$ exists and equals $\displaystyle \lim_{N \to \infty} S_N$.  So $(x_n^{(\infty)})$ will be in $L^1(\mathbb{N})$.

This just boils down to showing that $\displaystyle \lim_{N \to \infty} S_N = \sup_N S_N ( < \infty)$,  which is a basic exercise in limits of real numbers.  I will not go into details here unless requested. $\square$

Therefore, the desired ``limit object'' is in the space!

---

Now we must check that $\lbrace (x_n^{(j)}) \rbrace_{j = 1}^{\infty}$ actually converges to it.  To do so, we need another lemma, showing that as $j$ gets large, the "tail" of the sums are uniformly small.

**Lemma 2:** Fix $\epsilon > 0$, and fix $J = J(\epsilon)$ such that 
$$j, k \geq J(\epsilon) \text{ implies } \Vert(x^{(j)}_n) - (x^{(k)}_n)\Vert_1 = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(j)}_n - x^{(k)}_n \vert  < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Then there exists $N = N(\epsilon, J(\epsilon))$ such that for all $j \geq J(\epsilon)$,
\begin{equation}\sum_{n = N + 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(j)}_n \vert < \epsilon. \tag{*}\end{equation}

*Proof:*  We prove by contradiction.  Suppose that the above conclusion fails.  Then for all $N$, there exists $k \geq J(\epsilon)$ such that $\sum_{n = N + 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(k)}_n \vert \geq \epsilon$.

Now, for $j = J(\epsilon)$, $\vert (x^{(J(\epsilon))}) \vert$ is in $L^1(\mathbb{N})$, so there exists $N_1$ such that $$\sum_{n = N_1 + 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(J(\epsilon))}_n \vert < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Yet by the failure of the above condition, letting $N = N_1$, there exists $k \geq J(\epsilon)$ such that 
$$\sum_{n = N_1 + 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(k)}_n \vert \geq \epsilon$$

Therefore, we see that
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n = N_1 + 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(J(\epsilon))}_n - x^{(k)}_n \vert &\geq \sum_{n = N_1 + 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(k)}_n \vert - \vert x^{(J(\epsilon))}_n \vert \\
& = \sum_{n = N_1 + 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(k)}_n \vert - \sum_{n = N_1 + 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(J(\epsilon)}_n \vert\\
& > \epsilon - \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \frac{\epsilon}{2}.
\end{align}$$

Yet
$$\sum_{n = N_1 + 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(J(\epsilon)}_n - x^{(k)}_n \vert \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(J(\epsilon)}_n - x^{(k)}_n \vert \, = \Vert (x^{(J(\epsilon)}_n) - (x^{(k)}_n) \Vert_1,$$
and by definition of $J(\epsilon)$, since $j = J(\epsilon)$ and $k$ are at least $J(\epsilon)$, $$\Vert (x^{(J(\epsilon))}_n) - (x^{(k)}_n) \Vert_1 < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

So in short, 
$$\frac{\epsilon}{2} < \sum_{n = N_1 + 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(J(\epsilon))}_n - x^{(k)}_n \vert < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$
Contradiction.  $\square$

[**Recommendation:** *Now* you are in a position to do an $\displaystyle \frac{\epsilon}{2}$-style proof.  Try doing it yourself before finishing the answer.]

**Claim:** $(x_n^{(j)})$ converges to $(x_n^{(\infty)})$.

*Proof:* By Lemma 2, with $\displaystyle \frac{\epsilon}{4}$ in the place of $\epsilon$, there exists $N_1$ such that for all $j \geq J(\epsilon /4)$, 
$$\sum_{n = N_1 + 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(j)}_n \vert < \frac{\epsilon}{4}.$$

Since $(x_n^{(\infty)})$ is in $L^1$, there exists $N_2$ such that $$\sum_{n = N_2 + 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(\infty)}_n \vert < \frac{\epsilon}{4}.$$

Therefore, for all $j \geq J(\epsilon/4)$, and for $N = \max \lbrace N_1, N_2 \rbrace$ 
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n = N + 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(j)}_n - x^{(\infty)}_n \vert &\leq \sum_{n = N + 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(j)}_n \vert + \vert x^{(\infty)}_n \vert \\
& = \sum_{n = N + 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(j)}_n \vert + \sum_{n = N + 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(\infty)}_n \vert\\
& \leq \sum_{n = N_1 + 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(j)}_n \vert + \sum_{n = N_2 + 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(\infty)}_n \vert\\
& < \frac{\epsilon}{4} + \frac{\epsilon}{4} = \frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{align}$$

Moreover, since $x_n^{(j)} \to x_n^{(\infty)}$ for each fixed $n$ as $j \to \infty$, by similar logic to the "The first sum" section above, there exists $J_2$ such that $j \geq J_2$ implies that
$$\sum_{n = 1}^N \vert x^{(j)}_n - x^{(\infty)}_n \vert < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Therefore, for $j \geq J^* = \max \lbrace J(\epsilon/4), J_2 \rbrace$, 
$$\begin{align}
\Vert (x^{(j)}) - (x^{(\infty)}) \Vert_1 & = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(j)}_n - x^{(\infty)}_n \vert \\
& = \sum_{n = 1}^{N} \vert x^{(j)}_n - x^{(\infty)}_n \vert  + \sum_{n = N + 1}^{\infty} \vert x^{(j)}_n - x^{(\infty)}_n \vert \\
& < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon.
\end{align}$$
This works for all $\epsilon > 0$, so we have convergence. $\square$.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for the answer. Could you add in the last bit of the proof? I've been trying to solve it but I feel as If I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: Sure, coming right up.

Comment: Finished.  I do not claim that the above is the best way to go about it, but it is elementary.

Comment: Aargh.  This proof is completely superseded by the accepted answer to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328479/completeness-proof-of-ellp?lq=1